# My script works when ran on the console but it doesn't when scheduled on cron (?)

Tags: python, selenium, cron

I'm running the below code using selenium, and it works perfectly when I test it on the console. But when I schedule it on Cron for some reason it won't work. Is this a problem with Selenium? with Cron? what am I missing here??

```
import tweepy
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = '{}/{}/{} {}:{}'.format(now.day, now.month, now.year, now.hour, now.minute)


d = webdriver.Chrome(r'cromewebdriver')
d.get('https://deuda-publica-espana.com/')
deuda_total = d.find_element_by_class_name('contador_xxl').text
deuda_hab = d.find_element_by_class_name('contador_xl').text
d.quit()



deuda_hab = deuda_hab.split(',')
deuda_hab = deuda_hab[0]



PIB = 1208248000000

porcentaje = round((int(deuda_sin_puntos) * 100)/PIB, 2)
porcentaje = str(porcentaje).replace('.',',')



print(deuda_total)
print(deuda_hab)
print(str(porcentaje) + '%')

# Now the part where we send the tweet

consumer_key = 'key'
consumer_secret = 'key'
access_token = 'key'
access_token_secret = 'key'

# authentication of consumer key and secret
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

# authentication of access token and secret
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_status(status = '{} € total | '
                           '{} € por habitante | '
                           '{}% del PIB | '
                           '{}'.format(deuda_total, deuda_hab, porcentaje, now))
```

There is a bit more to this what I am showing above, as this is supposed to post on Twitter the results, but in any case, for some reason this won't work on cron.

For reference, this script is running from a Raspberry Pi 3+ on Raspbian, if this helps at all.

Any clues?

Comment: How are you finding out that your cron run script isn't doing what you expect? Does it log errors somewhere? If so, post them! If your script, like the example you show, only produces printed output, you might not see it if cron runs it without a connection to your console.

Comment: How about giving us more clues to go on?  What does "it won't work" mean?  What output is this producing?  How do you know it is running at all?  Maybe your cron configuration is wrong.  One thing you can do, if you aren't already, is write your cron command line to redirect stdout and stderr to file.  Then you can see a) that the code is running at all, and b) what it is outputting.  That output could be critical to diagnosing this.  There are many things that can be wrong here.  With what you've shown and told us, we can only make wild guesses.

Comment: As is, you might find useful information in your system logs or journal if your code is in fact running and you just have no idea what it is doing. - be conscious of what user cron is running your code as, and make sure that all the relevant permissions are right for the code to work right running as that user.

Comment: Cron doesn't provide the same environment variables as a login shell or as Selenium. Don't rely on PATH, use absolute paths when calling commands.

Comment: Ok guys I'm sorry I didn't give more detail. There is a bunch of code below the one I pasted that basically puts the information all together and creates a message in twitter. So basically if I run the code, I will have my tweet published but if I schedule it on cron it won't. Hope this makes sense now?

Comment: If it's linked to environment variables not available by default in cron, you could try this answer : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158930/198901 `bash -l -c 'python some_script.py'`

Comment: added the last bit of the code

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean @EricDuminil, the variables I'm using are just information scraped from a website and put together for a tweet...

Comment: @sombra2: Sorry, I wasn't talking about variables inside your script, but the environment variables needed by the shell in order to run python scripts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the chrome webdriver with the --headless option. You will not be able to run interactive applications or applications with gui via cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. adding 'export DISPLAY=:0' in the crontab file fixed it. Selenium was trying to execute but it couldn't find a display.